# Determine if point is in the 2D square/triangle

Tags: geometry

In my notes there is the statement:
For a triangle with vertices $a, b$ and $c$, any point $q$
inside the triangle can be represented by

## q = a + α ( b ‐ a) + β (c ‐ a)

### In which α , β > 0 and α + β < 1

I don't quite understand the 2nd statement. How do I do it for a square instead of a triangle?

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation of the second statement, let $$a*=a-a=0, b^*=b-a, c^*=c-a, q^*=q-a.$$ Each point on the line segment joining $b^*$ to $c^*$, which is not equal to either endpoint $b^*$ or $c^*$,is equal to $x b^* +(1-x)c^*$ for some $x\in (0,1).$ The  point $q^*$ lies inside the triangle $a^*b^*c^* .$ Draw the line through $a^*$ and $q^*$, which meets the segment $b^*c^*$ at a point $p.$ The ratio $r$, of the length $a^*q^*$ to the length $a^*p$, is between $0$ and $1$, and we have $$q^*=r p=r (x b^*+ (1-x)c^*)=(r x)b^*+(r-r x)c^*$$ for some $x\in (0,1).$ Let $\alpha =r x$ and $\beta=r-r x $, and write the equation in terms of $a,b,c,q.$